# What font is used in "Fundamentals of Corporate Finance" book by Jonathan Berk, et al?

Tags: fonts, font-identification, font-recommendation

I'm new to StackExchange. Below is the image of the font I'm looking for ...

The font is used by "Fundamentals of Corporate Finance" 3rd edition textbook by Jonathan Berk, et al.

[image: What is this font?]

I have tried all the automated-font finder website such as WhatTheFont!, Identifont and FindMyFont. But it doesn't work!

PS: You can click on the image to see the full size.

Many thanks.

Comment: Hi Dave Masorn, we have some [requirements](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2366) for font identification questions, please take a look and [edit] your question to include that information. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks similar to [ITC Clearface](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/itc/clearface/):

[image]

Comment: Dear SpEEdy Roby, Thank you very much. I think it is ITC Clearface as you suggested.

Comment: Can you please include an image for reference.